# How can I update the Codename One libraries?

Tags: codenameone

I tried and tried to run this code in a new "bare bones" project, but there is nothing to do, it always gives me the following error:

```
/home/francesco/NetBeansProjects/TestUUID/src/net/informaticalibera/test/UUID/MyApplication.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
                hi.add(new SpanLabel(Util.getUIID()));
  symbol:   method getUIID()
  location: class Util
1 error
```

Code that is known to work, it's an example that I inserted in the [Javadoc of `Util.getUIID`](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Util.html#getUUID--):

```
        Form hi = new Form("Test UIID", BoxLayout.y());
        Button button = new Button("Generate 10 UIID");
        hi.add(button);
        hi.show();
        button.addActionListener(l -> {
            String myId = "myUsername"; // do not exceed 12 characters
            Preferences.set("CustomDeviceId__$", Long.parseLong(myId, 36));
            hi.add(new SpanLabel("10 Random UUID"));
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                hi.add(new SpanLabel(Util.getUIID()));
            }
            hi.revalidate();
        });
```

I think it is a problem of updating the Codename One libraries, which maybe in a project bare bones are old. However, opening "Codename One Settings", clicking on the hamburger menu at the top right and choosing first "Update" and then "Save" I keep getting the same error. If I try to use the old version of the "Codename One Settings" GUI, clicking on "Basic" and then "Update Project Libs", the problem remains. I don't know what to do.

Is it a Codename One bug or am I not doing the right action?

Comment: What Util class is that? Ours doesn't include a getUIID() method as far as I know. Could it be a bad import?

Comment: I implemented that method a while ago and you merged my PR, after I fixed aome mistakes you noted. I linked the javadoc in my answer, so if the javadoc is present also the code is present.

Comment: The import is `import com.codename1.io.Util;` and the code is here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/654042a863eaf6a3b14f04f2adf3ccb4608b8dc2/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/io/Util.java#L2263

Comment: Oh. That's `getUUID()` which I forgot about ;-) 
But you're invoking `getUIID()`

Comment: Wow! The same mispelling mistake that I made when I submitted the PR. Thank you Shai, you just solved my issue :) And thank you for always being available.